# Failed upgrade, now stuck in recovery mode(Myphone model:my27)

Tags: factory-reset

My phone is now stuck and when I turn it on, it says NO COMMAND/Error

it happen when i update my system, because it always updates. I leave my phone at my room but when I came back, my phone says Error and when I try to turn it on it wont work again, its stuck!

I tried to reset my phone but it wont reset it says that its done resetting but its still stuck.

Please someone help.

Answer (score -1):

1. First, turn off the phone by using the **Power button.**
2. Press and hold **Volume Up + Volume Down + Power key** for some time.
3. When you see a menu with two options, remove your hand from buttons.
4. Afterwards, press the **Volume Up** to enter Android System Recovery.

[image: mobile hard reset]
 5. Select the **"Wipe data / Factory reset"** by using the **Volume buttons** and press the **Menu Capacitive key** for confirmation.

6. Then choose "Yes--delete all user data". Use Volume Down to scroll and Menu button to select.
7. Success your reset.
   Here I provided more [mobile hard reset](http://mobilehardreset.com/) solution.
   Thanks......!!!!

Comment: And how does this address "*it wont reset it says that its done resetting but its still stuck*" (sic)?

Comment: You appear to be here [for wrong reasons](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/124241). See [How to not be a spammer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)